# Enumerator Start Function, Return Yield

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, ienumerator

I am currently working on unity and I am trying to download data from web by using WWW class. My code is below.

```
  IEnumerator Awake()
{
    WWW imgLinks = new WWW(imgConnection); //Here I am trying to download image links.
    yield return imgLinks; //here image URL are supposed to be downloaded.

    string imgLinkSring = imgLinks.text;
    imgLinksArray = imgLinkSring.Split(';'); //and they are splitted by ";"

    //---

    string _imgURL = "No data.";
    string _tag = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < imgLinksArray.Length; i++)
    {
        if (imgLinksArray[i].Contains("tag:"))
        {

            _tag = GetdataValue(imgLinksArray[i], "tag:");
            _imgURL = GetdataValue(imgLinksArray[i], "name:");
            if (_imgURL.Contains("|")) _imgURL = _imgURL.Remove(_imgURL.IndexOf("|"));
            if (_tag.Contains("|")) _imgURL = _imgURL.Remove(_imgURL.IndexOf("|"));

            WWW imgTextures = new WWW(domainName + "showImage.php?name=" + _tag); //and here imageTextures are supposed to be downloaded by the URL's I downloade in the beginning.  
            yield return imgTextures;
            tex = imgTextures.texture;
            textureDatas2.Add(_tag, tex);

        }

    }


}
```

The problem is, this is working fine if i don't have Update() in my code. When I have Update(), the code jumps to Update function from **yield return imgLinks;** and runs the code inside Update and then finishes the start function.

What I want is, finish running Start function and then starts running Update function.

What should i do?

Comment: Update is run every frame. If your start method yields and takes time, Update is absolutely going to get called while that wait occurs.

Comment: @Draco18s So how could I achieve what I want?

Comment: You need to wait for the coroutine to complete before you do anything with its data. If you are doing per-frame actions on it, you need to check that the data has been fully downloaded first, and if not, do nothing.

Comment: @Draco18s Yes, I know that yet how could I do it?

Comment: `Check if the data exists first`... Hmm...`if(textureDatas2.count > 0)`?

Comment: If does not exist then do what?

Comment: `...and if not, do nothing.` Emphasis on the **nothing**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a bool field named `awakeFinished` which you set to true at the end of your `Awake` method. Then the `Update` method can check if `awakeFinished` is true before doing anything else, and if it is false, return.

Comment: How could I return?

Comment: I did the way and it worked so far, so thank you so much. But what I did a bit different. I did add awakeFinished and if not i just made this.start() in update() function, and in the beginning of start() i'm checking if started already by awakeFinished. Probably what I'm doing is wrong, i feel like i should not be calling this.start() in update but I don't know other way. Anything you recommend?

Comment: I don't quite understand, but could you just put the code from `start` at the end of `awake` and then remove `start` completely?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using Update, you could create a Coroutine that behaves like update at the end of your Awake method.

```
IEnumerator Awake () {
    //...
    //Old Awake code goes here
    //...
    StartCoroutine(CheckForUpdates());
}


IEnumerator CheckForUpdates () {

     while(true) {
         //Put your Update code here instead
         yield return null;
     }

}
```

The while loop will execute once per frame for as long as the Coroutine runs.

Comment: Could you expand it more? Like how can I do it? And also, I have codes written in Update() already, wouldn't it be problem if i change them now?

Comment: Hopefully my edit made it easier to understand. The CheckForUpdates method acts like Update(), you just need to start it manually.

Comment: I understood your way, when I tried it in a simple project yes, It's working thank you yet since I have functions connected in Update(), when I try this solution it is not working properly. Could you have anoter way you think?